# TurtleBot ROS - How to move to specific angle (using Twist)

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to set a specific angle for the robot.

I'm using simple python script I found here: http://answers.ros.org/question/203575/kobuki-unpredictability/

I am able to get IMU messages and get the current angle (in degree),  by listening to "**/mobile_base/sensors/imu_data**", and take the **yaw** from **data.orientation**,
and also to make the robot 'twist' by setting **move_cmd.angular.z**.

But how can I tell the robot to go to exact angle, without an ugly loop that trying to get near my desired angle?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223951/turtlebot-ros---how-to-move-to-specific-angle-(using-twist)/) by [Guy Peled](https://answers.ros.org/users/25191/guy-peled/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What do you want is a controller. If the TurtleBot doesn't come with one you should implement it. As you say the easiest way to do it is to make a node that listens for desired poses and sends a twist to the robot. The most straightforward is the porportional control in which the speed is proportional to the desired angle. Of course there are other options but I don't see why is this ugly.

---

Originally posted by [dfornas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25543/dfornas/) with karma: 68 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0